# If $\mathbb{E}[X^n] =\mathbb{E}[Y^n] $ then $\varphi_X = \varphi_Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, characteristic-functions, moment-problem

Let $X,Y$ be real random variables.

I know that if $\mathbb{E}[X^n] =\mathbb{E}[Y^n] $ and $\mathbb{E}[X^n] \leq \frac{Mn!}{r^n} \hspace{0.1cm} \forall \hspace{0.1cm} n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\varphi_X = \varphi_Y$.

I was wondering how can we weaken the hypothesis on $Y$, for example, is it possible to require that $\mathbb{E}[Y^n] =\mathbb{E}[X^n]$ and the bound be true only for even $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ? I think the answer is afirmative, but if so why should $Y$ verify $\mathbb{E}[Y^n] \leq \frac{Mn!}{r^n}$ for odd $n$ ?

I try something the inequality $\lvert y \rvert \leq \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$ to use that $\lvert y^n \rvert  \leq \lvert y^{n-1} \rvert \cdot (\frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}) \leq \frac{\lvert y^{n-1} \rvert}{2}  + \frac{\lvert y^{n+1} \rvert}{2}$ in order to use that $n+1$ and $n-1$ are both even but didn't menage to conclude from here.

Any help, hint or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: By Lyapunov inequality we get $ (\mathbb E[Y^{2n-1}])^{\frac{1}{2n-1}} \le (\mathbb E[Y^{2n}])^{\frac{1}{2n}}$, so if we have "good bound" for odd terms, the same is true for even terms

Comment: @jacopoburelli: Perhaps, you thought it too hard. By Cauchy-schwarz, we have: $$\mathbb{E}( |Y|^{2n+1})^2 \le\mathbb{E}( |Y|^{2n}) \mathbb{E}( |Y|^{2n+2})$$ This provides you a lean bound for odd terms.